# Why is it that enum always is in the state of which ever enum is listed first

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I will provide you with the code for where the enum is located.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using static KitchenObjectType;
using static PlateCompleteVisual;

public class KitchenObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnDestroy() 
    {
        Debug.LogError("I was just destroyed! "); 
    }

    [Serializable]
    public enum ObjectType
    {
        
        Lettuce,
        Bread,
        Cheese,
        Tomato,
        // Add more types as needed
    }

    public ObjectType objectTypes;
    public void IdentifyKitchenObject(ObjectType objectType)
    {
        switch (objectType)
        {

            case ObjectType.Lettuce:
                Debug.Log("Found lettuce!");
                // Handle lettuce-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Bread:
                Debug.Log("Found bread!");
                // Handle bread-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Cheese:
                Debug.Log("Found cheese!");
                // Handle cheese-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Tomato:
                Debug.Log("Found tomato!");
                break;
            // Add cases for other types as needed
            default:
                Debug.Log("Unknown kitchen object type!");
                break;
        }
    }


    [SerializeField] KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO;
    private IKitchenObjectParent kitchenObjectParent;
   

    public KitchenObjectSO GetKitchenObjectSO()
    { 
        return kitchenObjectSO; 
    }

    public void SetKitchenObjectParent(IKitchenObjectParent KitchenObjectParent)
    {
        if (this.kitchenObjectParent != null)
        {
            this.kitchenObjectParent.ClearKitchenObject();
        }

        this.kitchenObjectParent = KitchenObjectParent;
        KitchenObjectParent.SetKitchenObject(this);

 
        transform.parent = KitchenObjectParent.GetKitchenObjectFollowTransform();
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }
    public IKitchenObjectParent GetKitchenObjectParent()
    {
        return kitchenObjectParent;
    }

    public void DestroySelf()
    {
        kitchenObjectParent.ClearKitchenObject();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public bool TryGetPlate(out PlateKitchenObject plateKitchenObject)
    {
        if (this is PlateKitchenObject)
        {
            plateKitchenObject = this as PlateKitchenObject;
            return true;
        }else
        {
            plateKitchenObject = null;
            return false;
        }
        
    }

    public static KitchenObject SpawnKitchenObject(KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO, IKitchenObjectParent kitchenObjectParent)
    {
        Transform kitchenObjectTransform = Instantiate(kitchenObjectSO.prefab);

        if (kitchenObjectTransform == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to instantiate kitchen object from prefab: " + kitchenObjectSO.prefab.name);
            return null;
        }
        KitchenObject kitchenObject = kitchenObjectTransform.GetComponent<KitchenObject>();

        if (kitchenObject == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("KitchenObject component not found on instantiated object. Adding the component...");

            // If KitchenObject component is not present, add it
            kitchenObject = kitchenObjectTransform.gameObject.AddComponent<KitchenObject>();
        }

        kitchenObject.SetKitchenObjectParent(kitchenObjectParent);
        return kitchenObject;
    }

    

    [Serializable]
    public struct KitchenObjectSO_GameObject
    {
        public KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO;
        public GameObject gameObject;
    }

    [SerializeField] private PlateKitchenObject plateKitchenObject;
    [SerializeField] private List<KitchenObjectSO_GameObject> kitchenObjectSOGameObjectList;

    private void Start()
    {
        plateKitchenObject.OnIngredientAdded += PlateKitchenObject_OnIngredientAdded;

    }

    private KitchenObject kitchenObject;
    private void PlateKitchenObject_OnIngredientAdded(object sender, PlateKitchenObject.OnIngredientAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        IdentifyKitchenObject(objectTypes);
    }

}
```

So the Object Type enum seems to be always putting it on the state of what is listed first. I have tried switching there places and it does seem that it is always the first one. By the way I do assign the objectTypes variable in the editor. Thanks.

I have tried checking the internet for reasons because I honestly am clueless and very new to coding obviously that didn't work.

Comment: the whole [mcve] - namely the minimal part is lost on you isnt it?  so you dont show at any point changing the type so how can we know you set it to anything

Comment: At no point do you set the field declared `public ObjectType objectTypes;` so why would it ever have other than the default value? You should have seen that yourself when debugging that code, which leads me to suspect that you haven't actually debugged it. Where exactly do you expect a different value to be set?

Comment: It is wrong to name that field `objectTypes` because it cannot hold more then one value. Plural variable names should only be used where multiple values can be stored, i.e. arrays and collections or `enum` types declared with the `Flags` attribute and with powers of 2 used for the values.

Comment: why do you pass in an `ObjectType` as parameter into `IdentifyKitchenObject`? Wouldn't you generally rather check the type you already have in `public ObjectType objectTypes;` ...?

Answer (score 3):

> So the Object Type enum seems to be always putting it on the state of what is listed first.

Well, not necessarily. You're never assigning a value to the field, so it will always have the default value, so it's really about what the default value for the enum type is. There are two things at play here:

- The default value for any enum type is the "zero value" (i.e. the numeric value 0, whether or not that has a name)
- If you don't specify any numeric values when declaring an enum, they're provided automatically starting at 0

So if you had:

```cs
[Serializable]
public enum ObjectType
{        
    Lettuce = 1,
    Bread, // Implicitly 2
    Cheese, // Implicitly 3
    Tomato, // Implicitly 4
    // Add more types as needed

    Zero = 0
}
```

... then the default value of `objectTypes` would be `ObjectType.Zero`, despite it being the *last* value declared. (If you remove the `Zero` declaration entirely, the value will just be shown in the debugger as `0`. Enum values are just "named numbers" and it's still valid to have a value which doesn't have a name... it's just shown as the numeric value instead.)

Comment: I did try it but no matter what i assign in the editor its always unknown kitchenObject.

Comment: @Burrito_San: How fields get their values when they're assigned in the Unity editor is a somewhat separate matter. I would suggest taking enums out of the equation - see if you can get a simple `int` or `string` field to be set appropriately after setting it in the editor.

Comment: Hmm I see. Ok. Thanks. Ill just do that.

Comment: I did what you said and I was certain it would work, and there were no errors according to visual studio. But when i went to unity it said compiler errors must be fixed before entering playmode. So I closed my project and reopened it but while doing so it said there are compiler errors and asked if i would like to ignore or continue which was not recommended. Safe mode only had the inspector so I tried ignore. But this time there was a second error message saying failed to find entry points. Which means it couldnt find my script. I tried deleting my progress but nothing worked.

Comment: I haven't even changed anything in my project so this doesn't make sense. I haven't changed the files either, or anything of the sort. The only thing that was changed was my internet but that would have no apparent reason to affect anything.